# Use Case Diagram - How to represent system provided functionality

Tags: software-design, use-case

I am trying to come up with a use-case diagram for a social networking application. I have User as an actor.

I want to know how to represent the "People you may know" functionality through the use case diagram. This is not an action which the user can actually perform on the system, but which the system is providing the user. How do I represent such cases in my use case diagram.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for an Actor to be a person in usecase diagrams.  It can be a [system event](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/useCaseDiagram.htm) such as a timer, watchdog or on going batch process.  Have a system actor invoke the usecase "Show people you may know", which would hava a 'include' sterotype association with usecase e.g. "Show Messages" used by a Human user Actor.